# replacing a soldered i3-4030u

Tags: processor

So I dug up an old laptop (Lenovo flex 2-15") because I was looking for something to potentially start gaming on just for fun in spare time and very strongly need a better cpu. It has a i3-4030U 1.9ghz core but the problem is that it is soldered to the motherboard. Is this something that can be undone by professionals and upgraded for cheaper than just buying a new laptop or finding a newer one to upgrade?

Comment: Question. In what country do you live?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A web search for Lenovo flex 2 15 processor upgrade gave results that showed that the processor is Ball Grid Array (BGA) soldered so it is not upgradeable.

While one can technically desolder and re-solder a BGA processor, it would require specialized equipment like a BGA rework station and a lot of skill. It's very unlikely you could find someone to do that for you for a reasonable cost that is less than replacing the laptop. That's if you could even find an appropriate processor to upgrade with.